# Turn on and off 'Space Clearing' at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I am using the Tango3DReconstruction for unity, and I need a way to clear artefacts and items that have been moved from the initial reconstruction. I know that I can set 'SpaceClearing' to true in the TangoManager, however toggling it at runtime does nothing.

I looked through the Tango3DReconstruction script, and I found the spaceClearing only referenced in the constructor. Is it not possible to toggle space clearing on and off? I would keep it on, however it is too slow. I want to quickly reconstruct a 'rough' version of the map with SpaceClearing off, then turn SpaceClearing on to clean up certain areas.

**Edit**:

If it is not possible, what are my alternatives if I keep SpaceClearing off? How can I manually select a reconstructed region and delete it, so that the it can be reconstructed again.

Comment: How would anyone know this?  You are asking about a hardly-used asset script.

Comment: @Droppy Really? What is stackoverflow for? This is posted with the google-procect-tango tag. I am asking them.

Comment: I had thought this was one of the million-odd asset store scripts out there.  If it's a Google product then it does have a much higher chance of being answered.